# AdomDataRader returns the same value

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, mdx, adomd.net

Im developing a dashboard in ASP.NET whit a Cube in SQLServer.

Im trying to get the dimensions values to put into a ListBox.

When I execute the query, it returns the righ rows size, but the values are the same in eachone.

This is my code:

> MDXQuery = @" WITH 
>                                    MEMBER [Measures].[Label] AS [Dim Career].[Dim Career Name Area].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
>                                    MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueName] AS [Dim Career].[Dim Career Name Area].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
>                                 SELECT {[Measures].[Label], 
>                                         [Measures].[UniqueName]
>                                         } ON COLUMNS , 
>                                       [Dim Career].[Dim Career Name Area].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS 
>                                 FROM [DWH UNIT]";
>
> ```
>          using (AdomdConnection cnn = new AdomdConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CuboCnx"].ConnectionString))
>         {
>             using (AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(MDXQuery, cnn))
>             {
>                 cnn.Open();
>                 using (AdomdDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
>                 {
>                     while (dr.Read())
>                     {
>
>                         select.NameCareer = dr.GetString(0);
>                         select.ValueCareer = dr.GetString(1);
>
>                         lstSelect.Add(select);
>                     }
>                     dr.Close();
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> ```

And I get this, after parsing to JSON the List:

> [{
>       "NameCareer ": "TICS",
>       "ValueCareer": "[Dim Career].[Dim Career Name Area].&[Programmer]"   }, {
>       "NameCareer ": "TICS",
>       "ValueCareer": "[Dim Career].[Dim Career Name Area].&[Programmer]"   }, {
>       "NameCareer ": "TICS",
>       "ValueCareer": "[Dim Career].[Dim Career Name Area].&[Programmer]"   }, {
>       "NameCareer ": "TICS",
>       "ValueCareer": "[Dim Career].[Dim Career Name Area].&[Programmer]"   }]

Comment: I try whit this too:

while (dr.Read())
{
for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount - 1; i++)
{
if (dr.GetValue(i) != null){
if (i == 0)
select.NameCareer = dr.GetValue(i).ToString();
else
select.ValueCareer = dr.GetValue(i).ToString();
}                               
}
lstSelect.Add(select);

And got the same result...

Answer (score 0):

I solve It, was a really dumb mistake.

I was instancing my object out of the while bucle.

Once I put the instance into the while, the problem has gone.

Thank you everybody!